ngrok/ngrok docker image, unknown flag: --domain
Hey ngrok team or any other developers,
i have the following docker compose file
ngrok:
    image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
    command: ngrok http --domain=<my free domain>
    environment:
      NGROK_AUTHTOKEN: ${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}
    ports:
      - "4040:4040" 

however when running, i get the error unknown flag: --domain
does the ngrok/ngrok image not have the latest support for the domain flag?
i have gotten this to work on my mac by using the wernight/ngrok, but it fails on my debian raspberry pi which requires arm64
I have tired different images with no luck.

Looks like adding ngrok to the command is confusing the process. You'll want to remove that. Also, you need to specify a port number in the command. So, it should look something like this:
services:
  ngrok:
      image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
      command: 
        - "http" 
        - "http://host.docker.internal:4040"
        - "--domain=<my free domain>"
      environment:
        NGROK_AUTHTOKEN: ${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}
      ports:
        - "4040:4040"

